# Is there a way to go back and verify commits on github?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, verify

Is it possible to verify old commits on github I've already pushed? Simply because I want them to appear on my activity graph

Answer (score 0):

GitHub will show any commits in your contribution graph if the following are true:

- The commit's email address is associated with your account (and verified, if necessary).
- The commit ends up in the main repository (not a fork).
- The commit ends up in the main repository's default branch.

It shouldn't be necessary to do anything else.  No verification step is necessary, and anyone can do the push.

For example, when my commits are accepted into Git and end up in the `master` branch, they automatically appear on my contribution graph, even though I'm not the one who pushed them.

Comment: When I push my code to master it doesn't go to my contribution branch. Maybe I'm having some issue with the email account? I tried doing git config user.email and setting it to my primary email on github but still no luck

Comment: Is your code in a public or private repository?  If it's in a private one, you have to enable showing private repository contributions in your settings.

Comment: private but I enabled that feature long ago. I just re-licenced my jetbrains account (I'm using webstorm) to the email that matches my github. Now, when I commit from the webstorm IDE it works. But, I'm still not seeing contributions when I push from the command line, which is where I always make my commits :/ Any idea? And thanks for your help so far!

Comment: You'd want to look at those commits with `git log --format=fuller` and make sure that they're using the email address you want, and also make sure that you're pushing where you think you are (i.e., to the right server and repository).  GitHub doesn't know what tool you use to push, so there's something else that's making the difference.

Comment: This must be the problem! Author is not correct, do you know the command to change it?

Comment: You could try `git rebase -x 'git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author' BASE_COMMIT`, where `BASE_COMMIT` is the commit before the first one you want to modify.